# sort integer array in java class fairly basic from 2 to 18

Tags: java

i need to sort an array of the type intgere in a basic way (nothing too complex) for a school computer science project. It would be nice if sb could give me not only a one sentence answer waht to consider but also some code i can work with.

thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like an homework.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that this is a site where you can post a homework assignment and someone will complete it for free for you. This is not the case. You are expected to either show a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself, and/or clarify the exact reason you are unable to make an attempt. Read also: [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: guys i havent found anything useful with google so pls dont blame me for asking. and this is not a homework but a school project

Comment: What is the difference between "homework" and "school project"?

Comment: *I havent found anything*, there is THOUSANDS of tutos for sorting elements lol

Comment: the project has nothing to do with the lessons but with a work group that i am working in besides the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could've either googled it but since you didn't, use this bubblesort method:

```
boolean swapped; // to notice swaps during a pass
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++)
            if (a[i-1] > a[i]) {
                // Swap!
                int swap = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i-1];
                a[i-1] = swap;
                swapped = true;
            }
      } while (swapped); // another pass if swaps happened
```

It swaps the ints next to each other until you have them sorted from the smallest to the greatest number. If you want it the other way around simply swap the ">" with a "<".
I hope that will help you.

Comment: Please don't answe to non effort question, that thinks SO is a place to ask for code.

Comment: Okay I won't again but why are you downvoting my answer instead of downvotiong the question? @azro

Comment: I'm not the downvoter here ^^

Comment: @azro sorry then

Comment: thank you i've tried this and it seems like it will work

Comment: @user8452856 it would be nice if you could accept my answer as the solution to your problem then.